# For Soap NSURLConnection, Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, soap, ipv6

I've submitted my app in AppStore, they reject if due to following reason.

```
Hello,

        Thank you for providing this information. Upon further review, we were still unable to login to the app.

        Please note that apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.

        For information about supporting IPv6 Networks, refer to Supporting iPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks.

        For a networking overview, please see About Networking.

        Best regards,

        App Store Review
```

I am using SOAP Envelope service to use it,

**Here is my code**

```
@property(retain,nonatomic)NSString *xmlString;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableData *webResponseData;


-(void)method_GetUpcomingLotteries
{

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                             "<env:Envelope xmlns:env=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:ns1=\"urn:Lottery.Intf-ILottery\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:enc=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding\">\n"
                             "<env:Body>\n"
                             "<ns1:GetUpcomingLotteries env:encodingStyle=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding\">\n"
                             "<EntityID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">2</EntityID>\n"
                             "<Password xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">Smart@Winners</Password>\n"
                             "<SortBy xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</SortBy>\n"
                             "<limit xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</limit>\n"
                             "</ns1:GetUpcomingLotteries>\n"
                             "</env:Body>\n"
                             "</env:Envelope>"];


    NSURL *sRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://isapi.mekashron.com/soapclient/soapclient.php?"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sRequestURL];
    NSString *sMessageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue: @"urn:Lottery.Intf-ILottery/GetUpcomingLotteries" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue: sMessageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



    [request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"soapMessage===\n %@",soapMessage);

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ) {
        NSLog(@"hiii");
        self.webResponseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Some error occurred in Connection");

    }
}



- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Received Bytes from server: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.webResponseData length]);

    NSString * strXml = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [self.webResponseData mutableBytes] length:[self.webResponseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"---- %@" ,strXml);



}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    [self.webResponseData  setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.webResponseData  appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Some error in your Connection. Please try again.");


}
```

**My question :**

1) Please tell me do I need to change my method or I've to change the server end to transfer my API from IPv4 to IPv6 ?

2) Code for IpV6 using SOAP method under ios9 that work replacing NSURLConnection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799925/apps-are-reviewed-on-an-ipv6-network-please-ensure-that-your-app-supports-ipv6)

Comment: [Other potential duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=apps+are+reviewed+on+an+IPv6+network).

Comment: I'm not entirely _au fait_ with IPv6, but I guess it would have to do with whether the DNS system for `isapi.mekashron.com` resolves additionally to IPv6 addresses. Perhaps you could look into that?

Comment: halfer can you explain? is i have to configure my server to ipV6 at the server end?

Comment: I am not the right person to explain. However, yes, I think your web server needs to listen on IPv6, and your DNS server needs to reply with IPv6 addresses on request. I am sure these things can be researched with a search engine.

Comment: Anyway, you have an answer below, so I suggest you examine the link provided `:-)`

Comment: @iphonemaclover: No, you do not have to make any changes to the server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURLConnection method use with IPv6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138808/nsurlconnection-method-use-with-ipv6)

Answer (score 2):

At WWDC 2015, apple announced the transition to IPV6-only network services in iOS 9. Now from June 1, 2016 apple has made mandatory that the app should support iPV6.

If developers use the standard networking APIs like NSURLSession and CFNetwork APIs provided by apple, they should not experience any problem. Otherwise you will have to move your code to the APIs that support IPV6.

If you are looking for to use some standard network library like AFNetworking. According to this [site](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3517) AFNetworking 3.0 support IPV6.

Apple has a documentation on [how to test IPV6 support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html).

Comment: please check what i do using my soap api? is i have to change the API in server end to ipV6 ?

Comment: They are not mandating server site changes, only client-side. According to their documentation NSURLConnection it falls under CFNetwork APIs, so that should be fine. But since in iOS 9 most of the APIs of NSURLConnection are being deprecated, may be they are encouraging to use NSURLSession. But NSURLConnection should not give problem according to their documentation. If you have used hardcoded ip address like "10.0.1.121", use DNS. Right now I can only suggest you test IPV6 support as per documentation and see if you can find any error logs.