# NSURLConnection method use with IPv6

Tags: objective-c, ios9, ipv6

I have code my project using SOAP methods in NSURLConnection.Recently new version update reject it cause of ipV6 issue for ios9+

Now i check that for supporting ipV6 you need to convert code to standard networking APIs like NSURLSession and CFNetwork APIs provided by apple.

Is there alternative without converting my more then 350+ api , it will work with ipV6 .

Answer (score 1):

Now that NSURLConnection has been deprecated it's just a question of time before your code stop working with new iOS updates.
So whatever, you'd better plan using newer APIs, sooner or later.

NSURLConnection should still work with IPv6 tho. Are you sure it's not because you have been using an IP literal instead of domain name ? Ex: using IP like 123.123.23.3 is forbidden.

Also; please take a look at  [the transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html).

It should hint what triggered apple rejection

Comment: i dont know where is the problem , some suggest that change the method where as some suggest upgrate the server api from ipv4 to ipv6. Still confuse, i have tested my app in ios9 its work fine in normal network and wifi, but while submission in apple they reject cause of failure in ipv6 network.
Is i have to migrate the API in the ipV6 network as well ??? and then test with the same code?

Comment: my api url is something like : https:/api.xyz.com/api

Comment: Thanks god you don't have to make any server change.  Many companies don't support IPv6 (like AWS for exemple)

Does they give more informations about the cause of the rejection ? 
Are you sure the warning comes from your NSURLConnection  and not some other (possible 3rd party) API call ?

Comment: check my question and method used to call api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046187/for-soap-nsurlconnection-please-ensure-that-your-app-supports-ipv6-networks-as

Comment: Why did you duplicated your question ? this is supposed to be a bad practice on SE.
You was talking about 350+ API calls... That's quite a lot; much more than what is displayed on your other question ...